Can I have a destructor inside a structure in C++
I have a struct which has a pointer. It is always dynamically allocated. So I need to always need to free up the pointer whenever the object is created like this.
A obj;
obj->nums = new int(5);
delete obj->num;

struct A
{
    int *num;
    char c;
    int val;
};

Can I have a destructor inside A to manage the cleanup of the pointer variable. Can I have the destructor even though I don't have a constuctor; So my new code looks like:
struct A
{
    int *num;
    char c;
    int val;
    ~A()
    {
       delete num;
    }
}A;


Yes you can struct and class are the same thing. With one exception in a class all members are private by default and for a struct they are public. (So you can even add a private section to a struct too). Side note, in C++ do not use raw pointers like this but use std::unique_ptr which will call the delete for you. And I would add a constructor to the struct too A(int value) : num{ std::make_unique<int>(value); } (assuming you replaced int* with std::unique_ptr<int>) this keeps things symmetric, in your code the client would allocate and the struct would deallocate.

You can but you shouldn't. Your code is poorly designed and will can lead to double deletes, or deleting uninitialized values.  As suggested in the other comment, it is better to wrap memory management as tightly as possible, and unique_ptr will do that for you

In C++, a struct and a class are exactly the same thing, the only difference being default access (and accessibility) of members and bases (private for a class, public for a struct).   Both a class and a struct can therefore have a destructor.   It is not a good idea to allow users of the struct to allocate its members though - make the pointer private and only allow change it directly in constructors and other member functions.   In C, this is not possible (C does not support constructors, destructors, access control, .....)

See If only the destructor is declared as default, Is the copy constructor implicitly generated? and Can C++ struct have member functions?

This is nothing but RAII

See also What is the rule of three?. Reuired reading for anyone wanting to progress beyond beginner.

Yes. A struct in C++ is a class, but with default public access, and with default public inheritance. Hence, a struct can have constructors, destructors, member functions, etc.
struct A {
    int b;

private:
    int c;
};

Offers identical member access to:
class A {
public:
    int b;

private:
    int c;
};

The difference in inheritance can be readily demonstrated.
struct As { int b; };
class Ac { public: int b; };

These look identical given that everything in Ac is public. And indeed, these will behave identically. Until we bring inheritance into play:
struct Bs : As { };
class Bc : Ac { };

Bs and Bc are not equivalent.
Bs x { 3 };

The above will compile, but the following will not.
Bc y { 3 };

In order to make this work equivalently, we need to explicitly state that public inheritance is used:
class Bc : public Ac { };

As noted, your struct should handle the dynamic allocation in the constructor.
struct A
{
    int *num;
    char c;
    int val;
   
    A(int n) : num(new int(n)) {}
    ~A() { delete num; } 
};

As your struct contains dynamically allocated memory, you also need to read up on the rule of three/five/zero.

How things change.   When C++ was in its infancy, and there was effort to encourage C developers to make the transition,  a C++ class was said to be a struct, not the other way round.

I prefer class -> struct because the alternative may encourage thinking about C++ classes in terms of how C structs work which invites misunderstanding.

Yes, you can do that.
But why not allocate memory dynamically in the constructor! This way the constructor has symmetrical beauty.


Can I have the destructor even though I don't have a constructor.

Yes, you can, but usually you should not. Once a class has a destructor, it should also have at least a copy constructor and/or a copy assignment operator, either defined or deleted.
Exception: a class defines a virtual interface and doesn't manage resources.
See The rule of three/five/zero for details.

'No you can't' is a bit strong.  Live by the sword, die by the sword and all that

I think strict design rules are more suitable for beginners that confuse C++ and C. Variability will be trialled with some experience later.

I don't disagree, but saying that is not actually true.
